# Odoo asking to be refreshed

Tags: odoo

I changed the name of a view, and then odoo refused to start up and gave the error:

'MissingError', 'One of the documents you are trying to access has been deleted, please try again after refreshing.

I had this line:
    record model = "ir.ui.view" id = "project_view"

and changed it to:
    record model = "ir.ui.view" id = "project_viewa"

After changing it back again I still get the same error (after many restarts).

What exactly does it mean by refreshing odoo?

Thanks.

Comment: Where did you have changed .? Did you changed on view side.? and did you try after restarting server.?

Answer (score 0):

Changing of ID will change the db records of "ir.ui.view". So the problem should be in db side. un install the module and install new one with updates.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like some of your views in ir_ui_view got corrupted.

To rebuild all your views goto your pg database using commandline, and then

```
TRUNCATE ir_ui_view CASCADE;
```

Then restart your odoo server with **-u all** parameter. E.g

```
python /path/odoo/odoo.py -c config.conf -u all
```

This solution solved my issue similar to the one you are facing. But be sure to backup your database before using this technique.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try upgrading base, to refresh all the views and menus etc...

Answer (score 0):

You have to Upgrade the module.because any changes in xml file must be upgrade the module.